# Storing multiple values and picked entity with lowest value

Tags: java, distance

I'm currently looking to add a section to my program where engineers are selected for jobs based on their distance from a job. I've used the google api to get the distance from one address to the other but how would I store the engneers ID, their distance from the address and select whos the closest to the destination? A linked list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a linked list with nodes as an Engineer object class that you make yourself with ID, distance and job attributes, then traverse the linked list to find the Engineer(s) with the closest distance.

Or if all you care about is ID and distance, you could make a hashmap that hashes ID's to distances so that you only have the one hashmap instead of a bunch of link list node objects.

These are two solution out of many that you could use though, my suggestion would be to use whatever you are most comfortable with.

If you need a more specific answer, please make a more specific question.